# How to create a new activity in onValueSelected method

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I tried to create new Intent inside OnValueSelected inside pieChart object and got the following compile time error:

"Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener, java.lang.Class)'"

```java
mPieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

                int pos = e.toString().indexOf("y: ");
                String totalPrice = e.toString().substring(pos +3);
                for (int i =0; i<yData.length;++i){
                    if(yData[i] == Float.parseFloat(totalPrice)){
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                String company = xData[pos];
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ViewStatisticsActivity.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });
    }
```

I expected that the library will allow for me to create new Intent like every activity in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in the following line of code indicates the context of `OnChartValueSelectedListener`...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewStatisticsActivity.class);
```

...which does not exist but should be replaced by the activity context or fragment activity context. e.g

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ViewStatisticsActivity.class);
```